# 'micropico.initialise' not found

Tags: vscode-extensions, raspberry-pi-pico

For Raspberry Pi Pico I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code. I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6lkYTfcMEg) to set everything up, but when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> ("run > MicroPico > Configure Project" command) I get:

> Command 'MicroPico: Configure project' resulted in an error command 'micropico.initialise' not found.

I restarted Visual Studio Code and do the command again, the status bar says activating extension but nothing happens. Any idea why this doesn't work?